# JQuery Highcharts - dates being picked up in US format not UK

Tags: jquery, date, highcharts

I've been searching the API but can't seem to find a definitive setting to make my chart render all dates in UK format (dd/mm/YYYY).

Here's the way I generate my Highchart:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false // I added this as I read it will force highcharts to set the locale to that of the browser, but it seems to have no effect
            }
        });
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            title: {
                text: 'FTE Modelling'
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'FTE (Hours)'
                }
            },
            data: { table: "MainContent_GridView1"},
            series: [{
                type: 'column',
                pointWidth: 20
            }, {
                type: 'column',
                pointWidth: 20
                // total number of column's have been shortened for brevity
            }, {
                type: 'spline'
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

My chart is made off a dynamic table which changes based on different functions in the page, it has a leading column which is for dates (shown in the qtip and the x-axis) and this is what I am having difficulty with.

The containing table "MainContent_GridView1" has the first column which is dates from a database, and the remaining columns are for various FTE requirements. But in essence the table will look something like this:

```
<table id="MainContent_GridView1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>nameOfColumn</th>
            <th>nameOfColumn</th>
            <th>nameOfColumn</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>25/12/2015</th>
            <td>columnData</td>
            <td>columnData</td>
            <td>columnData</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>26/12/2015</th>
            <td>columnData</td>
            <td>columnData</td>
            <td>columnData</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For row 1 the above currently generates a qtip on hover and x-axis of 12th January 2 2017 (it adds up what it thinks are the months and upon reaching 12 increments it adds another year).

For row 2 it generates 12th February 2017 (for the same reason as stated above)

An ideal solution would be to set a global option so Highcharts so it will either treat all dates as set by the locale (which is how the data sent to the table is generated) or alternatively permanently set the format of all dates to UK.

Many thanks

elboffor

Answer (score 2):

Edit for getting data in the format you need.
You can set the format in the [`data.dateFormat`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.dateFormat) section. This will let you tell highcharts what your date format of your values are.

> Valid options include:
>
> - YYYY-mm-dd
> - dd/mm/YYYY
> - mm/dd/YYYY
> - dd/mm/YY
> - mm/dd/YY

I don't see anywhere that you are defining your date format. You need to make use of [`Highcharts.dateFormat`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Highcharts.dateFormat) or your [`xAxis.labels.format`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.format). This can be done on your tooltips or your axis lables (and any label really). You can set it like:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 36e5, // one week
    labels: {
        format: '{value: %d/%m/%Y}',
        align: 'right',
        rotation: -30
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @wergild,
That code sets the output, the issue I am having is Highcharts is assuming the input (that displayed in the table) is in the us format and is generating the dates accordingly, as such it doesn't actually fix the issue.

I think the answer may be by using the Highcharts.dateFormat, but the API doesn't display where to apply this.

Comment: @elboffor, updated to handle data formatting vs chart formatting.